# Label Automatically Disappearing (xcode, iPad)

Tags: ios, xcode

a label I'm trying to manipulate is automatically going invisble at the beginning of the start of my app, and any time something happens. I'm using xcode 7.

Here's the current code I have for a button that is manipulating the label:

```
@IBAction func button1Increase(sender: UIButton) {
    label1Health += 10
    self.Label1.text = String(label1Health)
}

@IBAction func button1Clear(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    label1Health = 0
    self.Label1.text = String(label1Health)
}
```

I have a button that is connected to the first function, which will increment the variable that the label is set at by 10. The second function is connected to a long press identifier that is connected to the button. All of it works perfectly fine, but the label is automatically going invisible when the view is loaded, and will reappear after an action happens to it, only to disappear shortly a moment after. I've made sure there isn't any code that would do this in the viewDidLoad() area of the document. Could someone clue me in?

Comment: I'd suggest you inspect the view hierarchy in the debugger to check if there's another view obscuring your label. Also, for these kinds of problems it often helps to temporarily set contrasting background colors for the view elements you're investigating.

Comment: Thanks, I made a dub mistake. My button was on top of the label, and I didn't even notice it. Thanks for the advice though, this helped!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not storing the data of your label...
You have to store this value in your device, so you can reuse it when you restart the app.

Here's some resources for you:

[NSUserDefaults](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/12/2/reading-and-writing-basics-nsuserdefaults)

[CoreData](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-from-scratch-core-data-stack--cms-20926)

With NSUserDefaults:

How to write value:

```
let myLabelValue = self.mylabel.text // 17 (for example)

let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject(myLabelValue, forKey: "labelValue")
```

Then, your value is saved to your device, so you can reuse it when your app restart

How to read value:

```
if let myStoredValue = defaults.stringForKey("labelValue") {
    print(myStoredValue) // 17
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my wording wasn't exact, and I think you've misinterpreted. The label isn't "clearing" itself, it's disappearing. As in, it keeps it's values fine. It's just appearing and disappearing again when anything is done to it. The label is there and has values inside of it, but it's invisible for some reason. And, it becomes visible when something happens to it, and immediately goes invisible again. I'll change the question above to reflect this.